# requirement.txt error in virtual environment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, web-deployment-project

I am running

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

instead of making requirements.txt my virtual environment is making only requirements file which is empty. Any advice?

Comment: maybe you have no packages installed in the virtual environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to check is your virtual environment is running. You should see the name of your virtual environment in parentheses next to the command prompt. If not, activate it and run your installs again.

If it is running, try running just `pip freeze` without dropping it to the requirements.txt file. If it returns nothing, then you need to run your installs again WITH the environment active.